# Type 'Card' is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

Hi trying to use the BasicCard thing in Dialogflow for use in Google Assistant and im not sure how to declare it and or initialise it. There is probably some documentation on it somewhere but I cant seem to find it.

Here is how i'm declaring it

```
const {
    dialogflow,
    Suggestions,
    Card
} = require('actions-on-google');
```

and how i'm using it

```
conv.ask(new Card({
    title: `card title`,
    text: `this is a card`,
    button: 'view more',
    buttonUrl: 'www.domainname.co.uk'
}))
```

and this is the error

```
TypeError: Card is not a constructor
```

Comment: Why aren't you requiring it as BasicCard and calling it as new BasicCard? It says so in docs.

Comment: Saw some code where they were declaring it as Card and not BasicCard so my immediate response was to do that. I've now used BasicCard and it works, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for you too use it you should require it as a BasicCard: https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/BasicCard

Then it should work.